# Zipcode polling on the basis of region

Tags: java, zipcode

Im writing an app that has to generate as output the diff between all the zips present in the east coast(US) and the zips present in once of our in house databases.
With regard to the above I have the following questions --

1) How do i in the first place get all the zips that fall under the East coast ? Is there any online API or library I can use to achieve this ?

2) Assuming the above point is taken care of, what would be the best way to display such a diff, given that the results might be extensive. I would want to display data to a decent level of abstraction.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

p1nG

Answer (score 1):

1. http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/
2. Import from CSV into your database, then select from it zip codes where the state is in whatever list of states you want to deem the "east coast".  An outer join between the two tables should give you all zip codes in that set that are not in your house database.